# Add Mouse Click to Existing Coded UI Tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am new to coded ui testing. We are using VS/TFS 2017. I inherited over 100 tests. A requirement of the tests is that they always start at the "Dashboard". The person who recorded the tests ended each test with a "Click 'Dashboard' link". I have since automated the tests so that they run after our nightly build. The problem is that if a test fails all subsequent tests fail because the screen is not back on the dashboard because the first test to fail did not finish and "Click 'Dashboard' link". So I want to add a "Click 'Dashboard' link" to the beginning of each test. One would think this would be a simple matter... but I am not seeing it.

If I open the test solution in VS and open UiMap.uitest in the Solution Explorer and edit the desire test I can see the "Click 'Dashboard' link" action under 'UI Actions'. What I would like to do is be able to basically 'Copy' the "Click 'Dashboard' link" and 'Paste' it at the beginning of the test. How does one do that without re-recording all 100+ tests?
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if you are still seeking help on this 8 months old question. If you are then the following links have good info on how to hand code Coded UI: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1055/hand-codedui-test-visual-studio-2013 and http://executeautomation.com/blog/hand-coding-coded-ui-test-with-uitestcontrol/

Comment: @Sohel, Thanks for the reply. No, need for that anymore.